# How to insert many items in one SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 20 items. Is it possible to insert 20 items only with one query (without loops)?

Comment: Yes, it is. But you should post some table schemata or code showing how you're approaching this currently.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187202/insert-multiple-row-using-the-same-mysql-connection

Comment: How are you coming up with the data for the twenty items? Are they from other table(s)? A UI? If a UI then how are you accessing the database?

Comment: Do you want to insert 20 records?

Comment: yes, I want to insert 20 records.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look into syntax like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES (item1), (item2), (item3), ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT into `table` (`1`,`2`,`3`....`20`) VALUES (`value1`,`value2`,`value3`,...`value20`)
```

Comment: This will not insert twenty rows. It will insert one row with twenty columns (if that's your table structure). Against a table with one column it will fail.